# permutation of 2 to 2 of a sample with duplicate elements

Tags: r, permutation

How do I get all possible permutation of a list with duplicate elements?
For example, 2 by with the vector `x = x (1,2,2)` I want permutation with repetition:

```
1 1
1 2
1 2
2 1
2 2
2 2
2 1
2 2
2 2
```

Comment: Please note since order seems to be relevant, this are not really combinations but permutations instead.

Comment: In addition to @RalfStubner statements, these are permutations with repetition.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achieved with one of the many packages for generating permutations with repetition.

```
library(gtools)
gtools::permutations(3, 2, c(1, 2, 2), set = FALSE, repeats.allowed = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    2
[4,]    2    1
[5,]    2    2
[6,]    2    2
[7,]    2    1
[8,]    2    2
[9,]    2    2

library(arrangements)
arrangements::permutations(x = c(1,2,2), k = 2, replace = TRUE)
## output same as above

library(RcppAlgos) ### I am the author
RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(c(1,2,2), 2, TRUE)
## output same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function `rep()` as follow :

```
data.frame(V1 = rep(x, each = length(x)), V2 = rep(x, length(x)))
  V1 V2
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  1  2
4  2  1
5  2  2
6  2  2
7  2  1
8  2  2
9  2  2
```